# Is there a way to trace which lines of code were executed in debugger or otherwise in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I am facing an issue and would need to debug several brf+. I do have a positive and negative case. However, debugging them simultaneously to track the flow in the execution of the method is quite cumbersome. SAP trace will only trace the methods and tables executed, which is not what I want.

I want in a method with several conditional codes, which ones were executed.

Comment: If you want to debug ABAP code called inside BRF+ but you are interested in only one specific ABAP code, the best you have is the ABAP Trace (`SAT`) in mode "without aggregation", which allows to see the methods in order, and you can compare two ABAP traces to see at what point the executions start to diverge (the test cases must be very close to be interesting). For BRF+ you have dedicated tools.

Answer (score -5):

Just found an amazing post on SCN that helps in this.

https://blogs.sap.com/2010/12/14/abap-debugger-scripting-basics/

Comment: Please post an answer that isn't contained in an external link, as per Stack Overflow policy (see Help topics).

Comment: This post on meta stack exchange explains in more detail why you shouldn't post link-only answers on Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: And I think everyone have faced orphaned SDN links or even documentation links (which are very confusing when you find them in notes).